# Database change updates in ASP.Net MVC 4 using SignalR and SqlDependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, sqldependency

I am working on an application through which any changes to a database will update the webpage at real time without refreshing the page using SignalR

Following the code I am using

**1. Model**

```
public class JobInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}

public class JobInfoRepository
{

    public IEnumerable<JobInfo> GetData()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AtlasTest"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [ID],[FirstName],[LastName]
           FROM [dbo].[Persons]", connection))
            {
                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new JobInfo()
                        {
                            ID = x.GetInt32(0),
                            FirstName = x.GetString(1),
                            LastName = x.GetString(2)
                        }).ToList();




            }
        }
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        JobHub.Show(); 
    }
}
```

**2. Controller**

```
public class AppController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /App/
    JobInfoRepository objRepo = new JobInfoRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(objRepo.GetData());
    }

}
```

**3. View**

```
$(function () {

        // Proxy created on the fly
        var job = $.connection.jobHub;

        // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
        job.client.displayStatus = function () {
            getData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });

    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#Persons');
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $tbl.empty();
                    $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>FirstName</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>');
                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].ID + '</td><td>' + data[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastName + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                    $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**4. SignalR Hub Class**

```
 public class JobHub : Hub
{
    public static void Show()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
    }
}
```

**5. Global.asax.cs**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
         RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AtlasTest"].ConnectionString);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


    }
```

On running the above code and going through the link ..//App/Index. I got the follwing error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GridMvcSignalR.Models.JobInfo]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GridMvcSignalR.Models.JobInfoRepository]'.

Is there anyway, I can fix it and make my application work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are having following statement in the top of your `View`:

```
@model IEnumerable<GridMvcSignalR.Models.JobInfoRepository>
```

Try to change it to:

```
@model List<GridMvcSignalR.Models.JobInfo>
```

Comment: When I made the above change. its redirecting me to an empty page. Can you review it..

Comment: @Dayakar Why do think it redirects you? Do you see another address? There are two possible reasons. 1) You have some error on your page and it redirects you to error page. 2) You have no content on your Index View. You show only javascript. Does it have something else?

Comment: @Dayakar 3)Sometimes it occurs if your browser blocks jquery. Then you need to add jquery link directly on this page